# Inaccurate Security Graph API Responses

Tags: microsoft-graph-security

For some odd reason the results that I am getting from the Graph Security API the past two days are inaccurate and I can't for the life of me figure out why.

If I query https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/security/alerts I am returned 7 old alerts without any obvious relationship, rhyme, or reason for populating my results. These are not the 7 most recent, and we have had more than 7 alerts.

For example, when attempting to append $filter=vendorInformation/provider eq 'Microsoft Defender ATP' I receive:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Security/alerts",
    "value": []
}
```

This issue appears to extend for me across all of the MTP services.

I can see the alerts within MDATP, and others like MCAS and ASC for example when navigating directly to those portals or querying their platform specific api's, like
https://api-us.securitycenter.windows.com/api/alerts for example.

I am getting data returned, it is just not the right data.

I am utilizing a Postman App registration with the SecurityEvents.Read.All and SecurityEvents.ReadWrite.All "Granted for MYDOMAIN".

I feel like I am missing something here. Any one else having issues? More than happy to share additional details that would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your feedback. Our MDATP team has identified and fixed the issue and it should now work as expected.